# Jquery POST request not being sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    swal({
        title: 'Choose your settings',
        type: 'info',
        html:"<form method='post' id='set'>{% csrf_token %}<input type='text' class='set-pref' placeholder='Enter your preference' name='input_val'><button name='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm f-14 mr-1' type='submit'>Set</button></form>",
        showCloseButton: false,
        showCancelButton: false,
        focusConfirm: false,
        confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
        cancelButtonText: 'Go forward',
    });
});
</script>
```

When the page is loaded, this code will show a panel with a form on it. On this panel there is a simple form which will send a POST request. This code **works**, the POST request is sent without any problem.

The problem is, though, that the same code with just a simple edit, doesn't work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#manage').click(function() {
      swal({
          title: 'Choose your settings',
          type: 'info',
          html:"<form method='post' id='set'>{% csrf_token %}<input type='text' class='set-pref' placeholder='Enter your preference' name='input_val'><button name='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm f-14 mr-1' type='submit'>Set</button></form>",
          showCloseButton: false,
          showCancelButton: false,
          focusConfirm: false,
          confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
          cancelButtonText: 'Go forward',
      });
    });
});
</script>

<button name="button" id="manage" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm f-14 mr-1">manage</button>
```

In this case, the panel is not shown on page load, but after a button is hit. In this case, when i try to submit the form, the POST request is not sent and the page refreshes, i've checked the console and no error shows up there. Can someone help me find what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove `type="submit"` from button and make it `type="button"`

Comment: Hello, if your issue was resolved by the below answer, consider marking as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to it :)

Comment: Hey, i thought i accepted it, i don't really know why it is not! Sorry for the inconvenience, i'll do it now @AnuragSrivastava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your button type as `type="button"`

```
<button name="button" id="manage" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm f-14 mr-1">manage</button>
```

Comment: Indeed that was the solution; i have no idea how did i miss on this. Thank you! I will accept your answer in 10 minutes

Comment: @Jack022 Ok, glad to help!